# How to know the Positioned properties from a RenderBox?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a Stack which contains a positioned children. 
I need to move one child to another , I can get the offset of the other child by

```
RenderBox box = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

But I can't exactly get the top and start properties to animate to

```
AnimatedPositionedDirectional(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),  
            top: ??,
            start: ??
```

Comment: i think you can use top and left properties for that. top:position.dy, left:position.dx. Give it a try.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya it actually worked gladly! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use top and left property to set position of widget using offset.

Top define how much you want to move from top and left define how much you want to move from left side.

You can assign offset variables dx and dy in following way.

```
top: position.dy
left: position.dx
```